Center contents inside a div while "lefting" individual elements
I'm building a really simple website and I'm having a lot of trouble with a <form> etiquette inside of a <div> one. I'm aware there are probably more "div-centering" tutorials in the Internet than stars in the universe, and it is a really "over-used" topic.
However, after I searched on a lot of different websites, tutorials and documentation, I'm unable to apply on my own code the logic to centering the items of a <form> etiquette while leaving some out. In my code, I want to place all content in the middle just as it is right now. However, I want the "login" label to be on the left. I tried doing it with the following css code, applying the text-align:left option but still no result.


.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #493c4f;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  place-items: top;
}

.container div h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Barlow;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container form {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  top: 0;
  gap: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.container form label {
  text-align: left;
}
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <form>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



And how it is looking at the moment:

Any help would be really appreciated, as I've been stuck on this for almost half a day.

Why are you trying to use both display: grid and display: block on the <form> element?

Sorry, I didn't realize it, just changed it now. Thanks!

You have to adjust your .css file by removing text-align: center; from the .container{ portion and adding them to the .container div h1{ and .container form{ sections. i.e:
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height:750px;
    background-color: #493c4f;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: top;
    
}

.container form h1{
    color: white;
    font-family: Barlow;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.container form{
    display: grid;
    top: 0;
    gap:200px;
}

.container form label{
    text-align: center;
}

